# Parse.com push notifications don't get to devices on background

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

Today I've implemented Parse.com Push service in my app. 
I've noticed that the push notifications are being sent only when the app is open. I've also noticed that whenever I'm turning on my device there is a message says "Unfortunately, tof has stopped". The Logcat says Unable to start receiver.

The full Logcat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context com.parse.ParsePlugins$Android.applicationContext()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2952)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:172)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1499)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context com.parse.ParsePlugins$Android.applicationContext()' on a null object reference
        at com.parse.Parse.checkContext(Parse.java:440)
        at com.parse.Parse.getApplicationContext(Parse.java:270)
        at com.parse.ManifestInfo.getContext(ManifestInfo.java:324)
        at com.parse.ManifestInfo.getPackageManager(ManifestInfo.java:328)
        at com.parse.ManifestInfo.getPackageInfo(ManifestInfo.java:358)
        at com.parse.ManifestInfo.deviceSupportsGcm(ManifestInfo.java:446)
        at com.parse.ManifestInfo.getPushType(ManifestInfo.java:212)
        at com.parse.PushService.startServiceIfRequired(PushService.java:222)
        at com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver.onReceive(ParseBroadcastReceiver.java:19)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2945)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:172)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1499)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
```

I've tried to search on the Web but I didn't find any solution. I guess that it's something about the receiver background operation.

I need an answer as quickly as possible, so if you know a bit about Parse SDK and it's push topic so please, help me 'cause I need to solve this **today**.

This is my code. 

MainActivity.java:

```
ParsePush parsePush = new ParsePush();
ParseQuery pQuery = ParseInstallation.getQuery(); // <-- Installation query
pQuery.whereEqualTo("username", User_Name); 
parsePush.sendMessageInBackground(message, pQuery);
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<!--
  IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" in the lines below
  to match your app's package name + ".permission.C2D_MESSAGE".
-->
<permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
    android:name="com.intap.tof.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.intap.tof.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

...

<service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
    <receiver android:name="com.intap.tof.Receiver"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <!--
              IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter" to match your app's package name.
            -->
            <category android:name="com.intap.tof" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

I also have this line on Receiver.java:

```
package com.intap.tof;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

import com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver;

public class Receiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        i.putExtras(intent.getExtras());
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

I need major help right now!! Please help me!

Comment: Hello?? Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've understood why I don't get the push notifications on background.

I've initialized parse sdk twice - on the `OpenActivity.java` and on `ParseApplication.java`. I've removed it from the `OpenActivity.java` and added this code line:

```
android:name=".ParseApplication"
```

To the `application` attribute on the `AndroidManifest.xml` and now I can get push notifications on background.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps below. This code works fine and run the receiver on background. The original answer link: https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_push/android/native/existing

MainActivity.java file

```
public void onCreate() {
  Parse.initialize(this, "APPLICATION ID", "CLIENT KEY");
  ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
<receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
    android:exported="false">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
    <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
    <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

    <!--
      IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter" to match your app's package name.
    -->
    <category android:name="com.parse.starter" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Permissions.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<!--
  IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" in the lines below
  to match your app's package name + ".permission.C2D_MESSAGE".
-->
<permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
    android:name="com.parse.starter.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.parse.starter.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

Comment: This is exactly what I have in my code. Take a look over there.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this.

```
public class MainApplication extends Application {
    private static MainApplication instance = new MainApplication();

    public MainApplication() {
        instance = this;
    }

    public static Context getContext() {
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Parse.initialize(this, " ", " ");
        PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, FabulaClient.class);
        PushService.subscribe(this, "Barca", FabulaClient.class);
        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
    }
}
```

taken from https://www.parse.com/questions/cannot-send-push-to-android-after-app-is-closed-until-screen-unlock