# Unable to receive Push notifications in Parse

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I have been trying to figure this out for the past two hours; I have performed all the steps necessary to initialize Push notifications, yet am unable to receive even the test notification.

On my app's dashboard, I do see a class named "Installation", which contains the object Id of the user.

If I try to send a push notification to all devices, it shows up in the push log, but nothing registers on the device.

To remedy this problem , I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the app in the emulator, cleaning the project, restarting android studio and logging as a different user (when I send the test notification, another device was registered in the Installation class). Nothing has worked. I am attaching the relevant code below.

```
public class MyApplicationName extends Application {
public static final String TAG = MyApplicationName.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Parse.initialize(this, "-", "-");
    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
}

  //To register the installation to each user that logs in
public static void updateParseInstallation(ParseUser user) {
    ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
    installation.put(ParseConstants.KEY_USER_ID, user.getObjectId());
    installation.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e!= null) {
                Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

 // some code 

  if (e == null) {
                 // login success!
MyApplicationName.updateParseInstallation(user);

  // some other code
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<!--
  IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" in the lines below
  to match your app's package name + ".permission.C2D_MESSAGE".
-->
<permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
    android:name="Package.Package1.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="Package.Package1.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />





<application
    android:name=".Application"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"


//other code


 </activity>

    <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <!--
              IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter" to match your app's package name.
            -->
            <category android:name="Package.Package1" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>


</application>
```

**EDIT**

I added some extra code to get more information, I added the following code, along with the relevant section of the logcat

```
public class MyApplicationName extends Application {
   //code for initializing parse and ParsePush

  //this static method will run everytime a user logs in
public static void updateParseInstallation(ParseUser user) {
    ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
    installation.put(ParseConstants.KEY_USER_ID, user.getObjectId());
    installation.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e!= null) {
                Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
```

So as soon as the user logs in, the following code runs:
     MyApplicationName.updateParseInstallation(user);

The push notification is suppose to run everytime an opponent is found:

```
protected void sendPushNotification() {
    ParseQuery<ParseInstallation> query = ParseInstallation.getQuery();
    query.whereMatches(ParseConstants.KEY_USER_ID, mOpponent.getObjectId());
    ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
    push.setQuery(query);
    push.setMessage(getString
            (R.string.opponent_found_notification,
                    ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername()));
    push.sendInBackground(new SendCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
```

Here is the interesting section of the logcat:

```
 09-18 14:32:28.290    2324-2358/com.teamtreehouse.ribbit E/com.parse.ParsePushRouter﹕ Ignoring PPNS push missing timestamp
 09-18 14:41:18.580    8824-8831/Package.Package1/W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 10ms
 09-18 14:47:28.500    2324-2358/com.teamtreehouse.ribbit      E/com.parse.ParsePushRouter﹕ Ignoring PPNS push missing timestamp
 09-18 15:01:14.660    1314-1350/system_process W/BatteryStatsImpl﹕ Couldn't get kernel wake lock stats
```

Ribbit was an application I was practicing sending push notification on before trying push on the current app. I do not why this app is showing up in the log, but I suspect it is the reason the push notifications are not working. I tried cleaning my browser, restarting android studio, but I get the same message in the log cat. Can someone please, please help me out here? I have attached the entire log cat below in case someone might be interested.

```
09-18 14:32:28.140    1314-1314/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Killing       2301:com.android.exchange/u0a27 (adj 11): empty for 1800s
 09-18 14:32:28.150    1314-1314/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Killing 2244:com.android.settings/1000 (adj 13): empty for 1804s
 09-18 14:32:28.160    1314-1314/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Killing    2142:com.android.managedprovisioning/u0a8 (adj 13): empty for 1807s
 09-18 14:32:28.170    1314-1314/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Killing 2114:com.android.dialer/u0a4 (adj 13): empty for 1807s
 09-18 14:32:28.180    1314-1314/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Killing  1870:com.android.defcontainer/u0a3 (adj 13): empty for 1808s
 09-18 14:32:28.190    1314-1314/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Killing 2004:com.android.music/u0a33 (adj 13): empty for 1812s
 09-18 14:32:28.290    2324-2358/com.teamtreehouse.ribbit E/com.parse.ParsePushRouter﹕ Ignoring PPNS push missing timestamp
 09-18 14:41:18.580    8824-8831/Package.Package1/W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 10ms
 09-18 14:47:28.500    2324-2358/com.teamtreehouse.ribbit      E/com.parse.ParsePushRouter﹕ Ignoring PPNS push missing timestamp
 09-18 15:01:14.660    1314-1350/system_process W/BatteryStatsImpl﹕ Couldn't get kernel wake lock stats
 09-18 15:02:00.030    1314-1340/system_process I/ProcessStatsService﹕ Prepared write state in 0ms
 09-18 15:02:40.080    1314-1314/system_process V/BackupManagerService﹕ Running a backup pass
 09-18 15:02:40.100    1314-1458/system_process V/PerformBackupTask﹕ Beginning backup of 7 targets
 09-18 15:02:40.120    1556-1841/com.android.inputmethod.latin I/LatinIME:LogUtils﹕ Dictionary info: dictionary = UserHistoryDictionary.en_US ; version = 1441827702 ; date = 1442613760
09-18 15:02:40.160    1314-1458/system_process D/PerformBackupTask﹕ invokeAgentForBackup on @pm@
09-18 15:02:40.160    1314-1458/system_process V/BackupServiceBinder﹕ doBackup() invoked
09-18 15:02:40.180    2324-2358/com.teamtreehouse.ribbit E/com.parse.ParsePushRouter﹕ Ignoring PPNS push missing timestamp
09-18 15:02:40.200    1314-1458/system_process I/BackupRestoreController﹕ Getting widget state for user: 0
09-18 15:02:40.200    1314-1458/system_process I/PerformBackupTask﹕ no backup data written; not calling transport
09-18 15:02:40.200    1314-1458/system_process D/PerformBackupTask﹕ starting agent for backup of BackupRequest{pkg=com.android.dialer}
```

09-18 15:02:40.220    1314-1458/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Start proc 27097:com.android.dialer/u0a4 for backup com.android.dialer/.DialerBackupAgent
   09-18 15:02:40.220    1314-1458/system_process D/BackupManagerService﹕ awaiting agent for ApplicationInfo{527c6ec com.android.dialer}
  09-18 15:02:40.230  27097-27097/? D/ExtensionsFactory﹕ No custom extensions.

Answer (score 0):

This Might Help you

http://www.androidhive.info/2015/06/android-push-notifications-using-parse-com/

Just avoid gradle and have a look at the Receiver and Manifest Files.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32549151/2378691) question. This is a question that I wrote. Copy the code that I'm using there from the question, and follow the instruction on the accepted answer (also by me).

ParseApplication.java:

```
package your.package.name;

public class ParseApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Parse.initialize(this, "", "");
    }
}
```

Comment: I looked at your answer, and I had already taken the exact same steps that you did, but to no avail.

Comment: Hello, please look at the edit, I provided new information.